# Circular shape of a 3D plots in mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, finite-element-method, plot-themes

I use several 3D tracing themes in Mathematica but I can't do it like that, I need your help
Thank you [image: example]

Comment: You can try `Plot3D[Exp[-(5 x^2+y^2)],{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3},PlotRange->All,
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},  x^2 + y^2 < 9],
Boxed->False,Axes->False]` to get approximately the second graph.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one possibly design of the 3D image of eigenfunctions on the disk:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`; reg = 
 Disk[]; n = 6; op = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] - 
  UnitStep[.5 - (x^2 + y^2)] u[x, y]; {val, fun} = 
 NDEigensystem[{op, DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] reg, n]

Table[Plot3D[fun[[i]][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, Mesh -> None, 
  Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50], {i, n}]
```

[image: Figure 1]